# I made a custom shape with the knife tool but I cant use the subsurf of it for sculpting

Tags: modeling, mesh

So I used a cube and the knife tool to make a custom shape for a sword pommel. The pommel has engravings on it that I want to sculpt but the subsurf looks awful. This awful looking subsurf makes odd artefacts when you try to sculpt on it

[image]

Comment: your shape doesn't seem too complicated, it would be easy to come back to a more regular topology, then either use Dyntopo, or Multires modifier, or simply resubdivide it?

Comment: Yes, you can use the multires modifier to recalculate the geometry to be all quads. Your model was probably a mess of an N-gon because of the knife tool being too easy to work with so to speak. The subsurf modifier is designed to work optimally with either a completely quad faced model or triangles. Not N-gons

Comment: Hey thanks for the response guys. I am really new to blender. Can you elaborate on the multires that I need to use? and what do you mean by N-gon?

Answer (score 0):

An n-gon is face with more than 4 sides. 3 sides = tri,  4 sides = quad, 5+ sides = n-gon. Although the use of tris and n-gons are sometimes a common part of modelling, both of them can be responsible for shading artifacts, especially near edges that are shaded smooth. More importantly to your scenario, is that blender calculates subdivisions best based on quad-only based geometry. See the example images below. The first images shows 2 planes - one with quad topology and the other with tris and n-gons. The second shows what happens to each of them (topology wise) when a subsurf modifier is added.

[image: Subdiv1]

[image: Subdiv2]

See the difference? This is one reason why people argue that you should keep your geometry as quad based as possible. A MULTI-RESOLUTION MODIFIER is a tool that aids in this pursuit. It is a modifier that can quickly reduce whatever geometry you have to being quad based (among other things) without loosing too much detail. Once the surface of your pommel is quad only, you can then subdivide and get the results you are looking for.

Comment: Hey thanks for the explanation Really clear now! So once I have my base object how do I use multires to make it quad based?

Comment: The multires can be a bit complicated, more than I have time to explain right now. Just google blender retopology methods/tools and maybe check out a couple of tutorials. The modifiers you want to look for are "multiresolution", "decimate" and possibly "remesh". However, if your model is simple enough (before subdivisions), you may find it easier to correct the topology manually.